# Postback in jQuery UI dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I've a gridview with some rows.
On each row I have an imagebutton on the right side of the grid that offer the possibility to delete a record.

Clicking on the imagebutton is show a dialog created with jQuery UI.

jQuery code is:

```
$("[name*='btn_check']").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Accept": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Code is quite simple and common for jQuery UI dialog.

So, now I wan to execute code when "Accept" button is clicked and I though `__doPostBack` could be a good solution.

So, I've created an hidden button in my gridview (near the imagebutton), then I've added this code to "Accept" function, as I found on another StackOverflow question:

```
__doPostBack('btn_hidden', '');
```

I've also tried to use this:

```
__doPostBack('<%= btn_hidden.UniqueID %>', '');
```

But without success.

So, which is the right way to execute a postback and how can I send the ID of the record to delete this record with code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should have a correct `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` set on your `ImageButton`. Then call dialog from the `OnClientClick`. As I understood you have only one dialog element hidden somewhere so there should be no problems with ids:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server"
    CommandName="Delete" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("YourKeyFieldNameHere") %>'
    OnCommand="ImageButton_Command"
    OnClientClick="javascript:return showConfirmDialog(this.name)"
/>

function showConfirmDialog(uniqueId) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Accept": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                __doPostBack(uniqueId, '');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    return false; // this is to prevent default click handler to cause a postback
}
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void ImageButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    // e.CommandArgument will contain the record key and 
    // e.CommandName will be equal to "Delete" or whatever you'll set on aspx
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working well! I've just added `event.preventDefault();` after `function showConfirmDialog(uniqueId) {` because it was returning "Invalid postback or callback argument" error. Thanks!

Comment: @s.milziadi actually it is enough to remove `return` before dialog call. Then it'll return false and there will be no postback. I've updated the code. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely the best, because event.preventDefault(); work with IE and Chrome, but does not work fine in Firefox causing an error. Thanks again